# One style set for multiple selectors

Tags: css

I want to apply css styles to `a` tags of single class `.video-title`
Tried to use

```
.video-title a, .video-title a:link, .video-title a:visited{...}
```

and

```
.video-title a, a:link, a:visited {...}
```

First one doesn't apply styles, second one applies for all a tags. What's wrong with syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.video-title a` applies the style to all a elements that are bellow a element with `video-title` class. e.g:

```
<p class="video-title">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
</p>
```

In order to select all a element with the video-title class you have to do

```
a.video-title:hover, a.video-title:visited, a.video-title:whatever {...}
```

instead of

```
.video-title a
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I admit I was considering it. This is the very very very basics of CSS, your question shows that you have done no research at all before posting this question.

Answer (score 2):

you want to select all `a` tags with class `video-title`?

css does it by `a.video-title`

Comment: nah, the class goes first, while the pseudo class is at the end `a.video-title:hover`